# Unity Build Error: "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\..\lib_burst_generated.txt' is denied."

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

I have a project in Unity which was built with version 2019.4.13f1. I opened it with version 2021.2.16f1 and since then when I try to build the project in an apk I get this error:

[image]

Also, I am getting these errors:

[image]

[image]

I tried to revert the project in the previous version and also tried a solution I found online to add to visual studio every workload possible, still nothing

Comment: Do you back those files up with google drive or one drive or something?

Comment: No I didn't....

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue as you with identical build exceptions after switching to 2021LTS.

I managed to work around it by going to Project Settings > Burst AOT Settings and checking off "Enable Burst Compilation" and "Enable Optimisations" for each platform, and then restarting the editor.

Of course if you need Burst compilation specifically, this won't solve your problems, but otherwise it may.